# Why is this regular expression capturing both the first and the middle name

Tags: regex

```
^([A-Z][A-Za-z.'\- ]+) ([A-Z][A-Za-z.'\-]+)$
```

for David Taylor Gator will capture “David Taylor” as the first match and “Gator” as the second match. I don't understand why the regular expression engine is doing this. Shouldn't it be greedy and capture the *entire* 3-word string using just the first group:

```
^([A-Z][A-Za-z.'\- ]+)
```

or does it do some back-tracking in order to produce a match?

Comment: The first part has a space in it. That is the problem.

Comment: If the first part captured everything, there'd be be no mandatory space and one or more character afterward.

Comment: It is also backtracking. So it would start by capturing everything. Then backtrack till it satisfies.

Comment: @d'alar'cop Dots don't need to be escaped in character classes as it is clear there that they are always meant literally.

Comment: Joshua answer kinda confused me, isn't space just another character? In his answer "{one or more name characters or space}" he seems to classify space as not being a character.

Comment: @daremarkovic I've updated my answer to make things clearer.  I had made a point to say "let's call `[A-Z][A-Za-z.'\-]` the name characters", so that space _isn't_ a _name character_ (although, of course, it is a character).  "one or more name characters or space", then, was to be read as "one or more of the following: a name character or a space", or "one or more (name characters or space)".  I've updated my answer to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth asking what parts of the regular expression are optional and which *must* be matched verbatim.

```
^([A-Z][A-Za-z.'\- ]+) ([A-Z][A-Za-z.'\-]+)$
*                     *                    *
```

The starred parts must be matched.  Every match must contain the beginning of the line, the end of the line, and a space.  Now consider how the other parts match, and let's call `[A-Z][A-Za-z.'\-]` the name characters.

```
^([A-Z][A-Za-z.'\- ]+) ([A-Z][A-Za-z.'\-]+)$
  -------------------   ------------------
          1                      2
```

`1` can match any sequence of the name characters and space, as long as there's at least one of these.  `2` will match any of the name characters.  Viewed at this level of abstraction, the regular expression is

```
{beginning of line}
{one or more (name characters or space)}
{space}
{one or more (name characters)}
{end of line}
```

The only way that this regular expression can match

```
David Taylor Gator
```

is as

```
{beginning of line}                      ^
{one or more (name characters or space)} "David Taylor"
{space}                                  " "
{one or more (name characters)}          "Gator"
{end of line}                            $
```

The other thing that could be considered, since there are only two spaces in the string, is

```
{beginning of line}                      ^
{one or more (name characters or space)} "David"
{space}                                  " "
{one or more (name characters)}          "Taylor Gator"    XXX
{end of line}                            $
```

but this isn't a match, because "Taylor Gator" has a space, but `{one or more (name characters)}` doesn't allow a space.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but when you mention 'or space', do you mean ONLY A SINGLE SPACE or "one or more spaces"? Does space being in a character set means 'this space can be repeated only once'? Because when you apply a repeat operator + , I think that applies to every character in the character set, including the space. So I think your explanation with the parenthesis on line 2 should be "one or more name characters or one or more spaces". Isn't space just a character?

Comment: It should be read as "one or more (name characters or space)", not "(one or more name characters) or space", and I've updated my answer to remove that potential ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks. One thing I don't understand, when you mention "the only way this regex can match ___ is as...", and mention "{one or more (name characters or space)} "David Taylor"" and then {space}: " ", are we considering greediness here? Because when I only have the first part of the expression "([A-Z][A-Za-z.'\- ]+)" without the second, it still matches "David Taylor Gator". I'm trying to understand how the regex engine processes this, it seems to be using back-tracking but not sure how it's doing it...

Comment: In the middle of this regular expression there is a space that _has_ to match something.  In the string "David Taylor Gator", there are only two spaces.  In _whatever_ way the regular expression could match the string, greedy or not, that space in the regular expression _must_ be matched against exactly one of the two spaces in the string.  If there were no space between the two groups, then the first one would match "David Taylor Gato" and the second one would match "r".

Answer (score 0):

Try this. But it will require a string with only 2 names... if you want the first 2 names - then remove the `$` from the end.

```
^([A-Z][A-Za-z.'\-]+) ([A-Z][A-Za-z.'\-]+)$
```

The first capturing group had a space, which is causing it to capture the first 2 words.

Comment: I'm not trying to design a more efficient regex, but trying to understand why this existing one works the way it does.